# qp file missing windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am getting QP file missing in windows phone 8.1 mobile when I tried to update my application.
Can any one suggest me on what exactly the problem is, I am unable to open my application.

Comment: what do you mean by qp file here?

Comment: I dont know..i am getting this error QP file is missing..when i try to update my app